# Relaxed.js is not rendering chart.js charts properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts

I am using relaxed.js to generate a pdf from an html page. This html page contains some charts generated using chart.js. When I convert this html page to pdf my charts are not being rendered properly.

Following are the reference images:
[HTML-Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdOFH.png) 
[Rendered-PDF-File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyQ1S.png)